# What is the default font-size of H4?

Tags: html, css

I am completely lost. The website I check for **CSS-defaults** is always http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html (I don't trust any other site)

And it seems they missed the `font-size` of `h4`.

Sorry to bother you guys for this, but it is important and I don't know how to check it using the tools like *firebug* or one of those...

Comment: It depends on the browser, I guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not there, because it's using the implied default `font-size` of `1em` (which also happens to be the average between the values for `<h3>` and `<h5>`). As others have noted, though, this may not be true for your browser, and you should really set it yourself if you want to make sure.

Answer (score 4):

HTML 4:
it SOMETHING LIKE THAT BUT EVERY BROWSER MAY VARY

```
h1: 2em
h2: 1.5em
h3: 1.17em
h4: 1em
h5: 0.83em
h6: 0.75em
FIREFOX 
h1: 2em
h2: 1.5em
h3: 1.17em
h4: 1em
h5: 0.83em
h6: 0.67em
```

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at your link it seems it's `1em`, i.e. the same size as normal text.

Answer (score 1):

The default font size of pretty much *any* element is browser-specific.  If you want a guaranteed size, set it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure on the exact value but I know that h4 is the same size as p element which I belive is 1em by default